# If Column 1 = Blank Then Column 2 in R

Tags: r

This has got to be super simple, but I cannot find it anywhere. I am trying to create a new column (field) in R that looks at two other columns--filling in blanks of one column with the values of another, e.g. below:

```
name    age1    age2    age
Bob     45      45      45
Clint           33      33
Dave    48      15      48
```

As you can see from the above, if age2 != age1, then age1 should be the default value.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use `ifelse`

```
with(df1, ifelse(age1=="", age2, as.character(age1)))
```

Comment: Perhaps I am doing something wrong. I had tried that but for some reason the values I get when there is a blank in age1 does not equal the values in age2. Any ideas why that might be? My acutal data has strings in each of the columns but for some reason the ifelse statement kicks back numbers.

Comment: @stevenjoe It could be because your column is `factor`. wrap it with `as.character` and it works.

Comment: Perfect. Genius! Thanks. Final script: with(df1, ifelse(age1=="", as.character(age2), age1))